# SP2010 - How to stop a Jscript filtering folders

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, filter

I'm on SP2010, managed by my company so unfortunately no access to server and can't add additional web parts.

I previously had the need to build an A to Z filter in a library. I have used a Jscript on the top web form to show the A to Z selection and filter a bottom list form depending on the letter I click on the web form.

I have a bug:
let's say that I click A, the list view is filtered showing only the folders starting with A. 
Now if I enter in one of this folders, unfortunately the filter remains applied so I can't see any file/folders contained in this folder. I'd like a way to undo the Jscript filter once I enter in one of the folders in the list view. Is that possible adding any code to the following script? 
On the list view of course I am not allowed to add script as this functionality is only allowed on the web form.

This is the Jscript I have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function qs(paramName) {
   var args = document.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
   for(j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
   nameValues = args[j].split("=");
   if(nameValues[0] == paramName) return nameValues[1];
   }
   return null;
   }

    var filterField = "FL";
    var filterValuesDelimiter = " : ";
    var filterValues = new Array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
    var selectedValueStyle = "font-weight: bold;";
    var filterDivStyle = "margin: 5px;";
    var filterLinks = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < filterValues.length; i++) {
            filterLinks.push('<a ' + (qs("FilterValue1") == filterValues[i] ? 'style="' + selectedValueStyle + ' ' : '') + 'href="' + document.location.pathname + '?FilterField1=' + filterField + '&FilterValue1=' + filterValues[i] + '">' + filterValues[i] + '</a>');
    }
    document.write('<div style="' + filterDivStyle + '">' + filterLinks.join(filterValuesDelimiter) + '</div>' + '</br>' + 'Please select a letter to view the available customer documentation');
    </script>
```

Ok quick addition, I think I understood what I need:

I need in some way to handle any click I make on any folder in the bottom document form web part, and before the folder content is loaded I need some JScript code that removes the existing filter from the URL, but then it still has to complete the loading of the content of the folder.
I have been able to get access to SPDesigner so now I should be able to add code in the DispForm.aspx page.

Anyone knows which event on the form allows me to catch the moment I click on ANY folder in the library and which instructions can I use to remove the FilterValue but not stopping the next page to load?

Thanks